# Jhipster and Postgres connection

Tags: database, postgresql, jhipster

I'm trying to run the project in Jhipster based on this tutorial by the creator himself :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1MEM8PdAzQ but it can't connect to Postgres

See errors below:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:473)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:203)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:146)
at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:35)
at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:47)
at org.postgresql.jdbc42.AbstractJdbc42Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc42Connection.java:21)
at org.postgresql.jdbc42.Jdbc42Connection.<init>(Jdbc42Connection.java:28)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:415)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:282)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:316)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:518)
```

How do I connect Jhipster with postgreSQL? I am a newbie on jhipster

Comment: And did you configure your app to use the password?

Comment: Check datasource configuration in your `application-*.yml` file. This is not specific to JHipster, it's pure spring boot.

Comment: None of this helps. What are the `application-*.yml` files supposed to look like to integrate with Posgres?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JHipster creates 3 configuration files: -

1. `application.yml` - main Spring Boot configuration file.
2. `application-dev.yml`
3. `application-prod.yml`

The `application.yml` file contains common properties, the other 2 hold specific properties to development and production environments.

If you look at `application-dev.yml` you'll see something like the following: -

```
    datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myapp
        username: myapp
        password:
```

However, you still have to create your PostgreSQL database - the easiest way is via the pgAdmin tool but you can also create it via command line tools - a quick google will help you there!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to work with docker compose file Version 3 in docker swarm mode, where it is best practice to use docker secrets, then you can create an .application.env-file and link it in your docker-compose.yml (Version 2) with 'env_file:'

```
$ cat .application.env

SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/database_name
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USER=database_user
SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=database_password
JHIPSTER_SLEEP=10

[...]
```

At least I use it this way to keep the credentials away from my jhipster-projects, which are on Github, where I also want to put the *.yml-files.